# Get part of PHP file from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, templates

Is it possible to take a specific part of code from one php file. For a project I have 12 page templates. So in WordPress when I make a new page and want to select a page template, a long list will appear with 12 months.

Here an example of couple months.

[Januari, Fabruari, Maart, April etc..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKEUS.png)

[image: Januari, Fabruari, Maart, April etc..]

So the question will be, is it possible to place all php code in one page template. And when you go to a specific url it takes a look to the end of the domain and based on that one part of php code..

Example:

www.domain.com/januari

Takes the part from the url /januari
**This is Januari**

www.domain.com/februari

Takes the part from the url /februari
**This is Februari**

In future there will be a lot of page templates so it will look really messy. It should be cleaner if there will be one page template "Months" with all content in it. Hope you understand the problem!

Thanks!

Comment: That is called "routing" and can be accomplished with URL rewriting.

Comment: Can you provide the PHP file that is handling the url changes and add the relevant code to see where you are at right now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches to this problem. My approach will let you keep separate PHP files for each month but only one Page Template will be used.

Let's say `page-template-month.php` is your template file. And your month specific files have the following structure

`theme-root /
 - template-parts /
 - - january.php
 - - february.php
 ...`

Now, the approach to get your specific query term and build logic around it.

### Using `get_the_ID()`

The above function returns the post/page ID and you can build your logic around that ID. Now, your `page-template-month.php` file will have the following snippet

```
switch( get_the_ID() ) {
    case 5:
    // let's assume it's the page for January
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/january' );
    break;

    case 18:
    // let's assume it's the page for February
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/february' );
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is the perfect solution for me. It keeps all files seperated and clean. Thank you very much Junaid!

Comment: @HesselvanderVeen Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the global `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to identify which path was used to get to your PHP script. Then you can print the specific parts based upon `if` conditions or a `switch case`:

For the url `www.domain.com/januari` `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be `/januari`, for `www.domain.com/februari` ir will be `/februari`, etc...

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    case '/januari':
        //January code here
        break;
    case '/februari':
        //February code her
        break;
    //...
}
```

But note, that for the URL `www.domain.com/januari?some=get&params` `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be `/januari?some=get&params`.

Comment: I know OP didn't ask for this but this won't work in case their are GTM trackers or any kind of URL params. i.e. example.com/january?ref=so

Comment: @Junaid As stated in my last edit. He still can use simple php functions to filter it out, but i will let OP figure this out himself.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any PHP methods for that.

Just use the concept of **Page Slug in Wordpress**.

here is the code which gives you the slug of current opened page.

```
<?php

global $post;
$post_slug = $post->post_name;

switch ($post_slug) {
    case 'january':
        // page for January
        get_template_part('template-parts/january');
        break;

    case 'februari':
        //  page for februari
        get_template_part('template-parts/februari');
        break;
        ... and so on
}
```

By getting slug into variable '$post_slug' you can apply your conditional statements to compare the value with your paremeters.

OR also you can prefer [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) method of wp to compare current page with your params.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can with get the actual link with and cut it

`$actualLink = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$whatYouWant = substr($actualLink, strpos($actualLink, "/")[1]);`

But why not use $_GET ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have chosen for Junaid his solution. It keeps it realy clean and separates the php files.

Comment: You're welcome, but i think Philipp Maurer solution is maybe more clean. Good luck ;)